# wrong behaviour of mouse pointer

Tags: mouse, unity, mouse-gestures

Currently i am using ubuntu 14.04.
my mouse pointer is showing wrong coordinates

please refer to following screenshots:-

here you can see **pointer** is slightly moved left..

[image]

more example :-

[image]

here the pointer is also slightly moved.

this comes problem occurs sometimes.when i close that application and run again the pointer runs fine !

**ANY SOLUTIONS ?**

Comment: You may get better answers on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: @JosephFarah is asked on Askubuntu but no any answers :)

Comment: I see. However, [cross-posting is discouraged on all Stack Exchange sites](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#Cross-posting). You may want to consider asking the moderators to migrate the post instead.